# Changing PATH in zsrhc depending on the selected ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, chruby

Is it possible that the PATH entries in the zshrc automatically adapt to the selected ruby version? At the moment the zshrc contains e.g.

```
export PATH="/Users/mariopeischl/.gem/ruby/3.1.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/mariopeischl/.gem/ruby/3.1.0/gems:$PATH"
```

If I now change the used ruby version with

```
$ chruby 3.0.3
```

I have to change the PATH entries manually each time. Is there a way to automate this with a variable?

Comment: I don't understand why you apparently need to update the `PATH` manually at all, because [a primary feature of the `chruby` library is that **it updates your `$PATH`**](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#features).

Comment: Maybe you haven't installed `chruby` correctly? Because you're literally trying to solve to problem that `chruby` already should be solving for you.

Comment: @TomLord You are right! Now I know what the problem is. In the osx terminal the switching works. However, the used ruby version is not taken over when using it in the VSCode terminal. If I want to use a special ruby version there, I have to run chruby there (VSCode terminal). Is this normal behavior?